# react-router-dom@6.4.1 not rendering components and also not logging any errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

`react-router-dom@6.4.1` is not rendering components.

I haven't coded React in a while now. I am trying to utilize `react-router` but something seems to be wrong. There's no error emitted but the components won't render. So many updates to `react-router`, it tough to keep up with.

[image: Preview]

**Link to [github repo](https://github.com/Chris-Imade/dashboard-challenge)**

This is a sample of my root file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './app/store';
import './index.css';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Calendar, Message, Settings, Team } from './components';
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import Aside from './root';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Aside />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/messages",
        element: <Message />
      },
      {
        path: "/team-members",
        element: <Team />
      },
      {
        path: "/calendar",
        element: <Calendar />
      },
      {
        path: "/settings",
        element: <Settings />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a complete [mcve] so we can see where any routes and content is possibly rendered.

Comment: I forked your repo into a codesandbox and as far as I can tell, it's rendering just fine, I see the routed content. The "issue" I see with with the layout. All the routed content is rendered ***below*** the sidebar menu "thing".

Answer (score 1):

Check your CSS layout, your components are rendered, but they are at the bottom of the page.

[image: screenshot of project]

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced the same trouble and here is solution:

Go to your main Container, where you want to see children.
then

```
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
```

then
inser `<Outlet />` component, in `<div>` where you want to render items.

Your code: If you want to render `<Team/>` you should import `<Outlet/>` to component where you want to see `<Team/>`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Aside = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            Welcome to Your personal gym
            <Link to='/login'>Log In</Link>
            <Link to='/registration'>Sign In</Link>
            <Outlet/>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Aside;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can read it from here:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet